# kibana not able to connect to server elasticsearch index - ECONNREFUSED

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5, econnrefused, kibana-5

I have elasticsearch server running having indexes, say server  XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200.

I have index in the server ES cluster XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200 for which I am trying to create dashboards in my localhost:5601 (Kibana)

In my kibana.yml I have this configuration:

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "localhost"

# The URL of the Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.url: "http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"
```

In Elasticsearch.yml I have this config:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0 (to accept all the IPs) 
http.port: 9200
```

But I am getting this error when running kibana.yml :

connect ECONNREFUSED http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200
Unable to connect to ElasticSearch at http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200

Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong here to get the kibana up and running with the server index of ES?

Comment: can you `curl http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200` from your kibana host?

Comment: Nope. Not able to from my kibana host

Comment: That for sure will work provided your Kibana host can see your ES host.

Comment: What if you have your ES host as 127.0.0.1 or localhost, if you're running it localhost?

Comment: can you connect to ES host from your kibana host using telnet ?

Comment: there was some firewall issue. it works fine now. thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your `kibana.yml` put this configuration:

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: Worked for me. Also had to set `network.host: 0.0.0.0` on `elasticsearch.yml`.